# Need help pulling into multiple columns from one database table - mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Afternoon all,

A very quick question... a friend has set up a form for me using mysql_query. Since he wrote this, I have added an extra column into the database, which I want to pull through into the form.

However I can't seem to get this extra column to appear (labelled Currency). The reason I need it is the query below will pulls back a value and the £ symbol. Because I want to display not only £, but also € prices, I need this extra column to pull through (obviously I will have to remove the £ from the echo below too).

I've tried adding the extra column (Currency) to the code, e.g. "SELECT Room, **Currency**, Price FROM Spa_Upgrades

but this hasn't worked.

The code is:

```
 <?php 
            if (isset($id))
                {
                $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT Room, Price FROM Spa_Upgrades WHERE Spa_Upgrades.Spa_Id = '".$id."' AND Spa_Upgrades.Id = '".$pack."' order by Spa_Upgrades.Order");
                $rows = mysql_num_rows($query2);
                if($rows==0) {echo "disabled='disabled'/>";} 
                else
                    {
                    echo "/>";
                    echo "<option value='Default'>Please Select</option>";
                    for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
                        {
                        $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
                        echo "<option value='".$result2[0]."&nbsp;&pound;".$result2[1]."pp'>$result2[0]&nbsp;&pound;$result2[1]pp</option>";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Hugely grateful if someone can solve this!

Thanks,
Motley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the query as follows:

```
SELECT Room, Price, Currency FROM Spa_Upgrades ...
```

Alter the line beginning `echo` inside the `for` loop: replace `&pound;` with `$result2[2]` wherever it appears. (Or if the `Currency` column doesn't contain the HTML entity for the currency symbol, then replace `&pound;` with appropriate code to obtain the symbol from the `Currency` column entry.)

Comment: Thanks Hammerite - replaced &pound; with $result2[2]! What did you mean replace &pound; with appropriate code for the currency symbol needed - this wouldn't work as there's ony one form and depending on where users click in from it would be either a £ or €.

Comment: What I meant is that I wasn't sure whether you were storing `&pound;`, `&euro;` in the database column, or whether you were storing integer IDs to those currencies which you would then have to translate into the appropriate symbols. It looks like it is the former, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`
- A good practice as well is to separate data retrieving from display logic

Try this:

```
<?php

$results = array();

if (isset($id))
{
  $resource = mysql_query("SELECT room, currency, price FROM Spa_Upgrades
    WHERE Spa_Upgrades.Spa_Id = '".intval($id)."' AND Spa_Upgrades.Id = '".intval($pack)."'
    order by Spa_Upgrades.Order");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
    $results[] = $row;
}

?>
<select name="..." <?php echo (count($results) > 0 ? '' : 'disabled') ?>>
  <option value="Default">Please Select</option>
  <?php
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
      $value = $result['room'].' '.$result['currency'].$result['price'].'pp';
      echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($value).'">'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</option>'."\n";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Why should you use fetch_assoc instead of fetch_array and can you clarify what you mean by separating data retrieving from data logic? Cheers

Comment: "Why should you use `fetch_assoc` instead of `fetch_array` ?" => using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, if you add a column or change column order in `SELECT`, you won't need to change anything else in your code. For example, with `mysql_fetch_array()` here, you must change `$result2[1]` to `$result2[2]` everywhere to get the price, after adding the "currency" column.

Comment: "can you clarify what you mean by separating data retrieving from data logic?" => I said "display logic", not "data logic". It simply makes code easier to reuse, therefore more easy to evolve, more readable... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the column to the output... I would also switch to an associative array otherwise if you add a column and its not at the end you have to change all the indexes.

```
        if (isset($id))
            {
            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT Room, Price, Currency FROM Spa_Upgrades WHERE Spa_Upgrades.Spa_Id = '".$id."' AND Spa_Upgrades.Id = '".$pack."' order by Spa_Upgrades.Order");
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($query2);
            if($rows==0) {echo "disabled='disabled'/>";} 
            else
                {
                echo "/>";
                echo "<option value='Default'>Please Select</option>";
                for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
                    {
                    $result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
                    $value = $result2['Room'] . '&nbsp;' . $result2['Currency'].$result2['Price'].'pp';

                    echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, Prodigitalson - can you tell me what you mean by assoc_array and having to change the indexes?

Comment: When you use `mysql_fetch_assoc` you get the columns in an array indexed by the column name so you can access them like `$result['column_name`]` when you use `mysql_fetch_num` they are indexed by their position order in the select part of the query query starting at `0` so if this query changes you have to change how you use the variable in the code for example what was once `$result[0]` might become `$result[1]`.